# CSS content with the before selector in mobile browsers not displayed

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I added a content before the site title with the `::before` selector. The content is seen / displayed in the desktop browsers, but not in mobile browsers (at least in Google Chrome and in the default browser on my Android smartphone). Why this happens and how it can be solved?

```
.site-title a::before {
    color: firebrick;
    content: "Ψ ";
}
```

The site in discussion is [psihoterapeut.md](https://psihoterapeut.md)

Comment: maybe a browser engine issue ? like webkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Unicode character instead: `03a8` (Greek capital letter PSI) or `03c8` (Greek small letter PSI)

and the problem looks like the font, you are using `cursive`, try to remove that font.

```css
div::before {
 color: firebrick;
 content: "\03a8"
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't helped.

Comment: thats most likely because you are using cursive as a font, try to remove that

Comment: I added a `font-family: initial;` property to the before content and this solved my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. I've updated the answer to have my comment on it